# UIImage.ciImage returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimage, ciimage

I am having some problem getting a CIImage from my UIImage in extension.
I am trying to apply a WhitePointAdjust on the UIImage.

Here is my code:

```
extension UIImage{
enum ImageError: Error {
    case filterLookupError(String)
    case filterError(CIFilter)
    case ciImageError(CIImage?)
    case cgImageError(CIImage, CGRect)
}
func applyWhitePointAdjustment(_ whiteColor: UIColor) -> UIImage?{
    let context = CIContext(options: nil)

    let filterName = "CIWhitePointAdjust"
    guard let wpaFilter = CIFilter(name: filterName) else {
        ImageError.filterLookupError("filter not found: " + filterName).handle()
        return nil
    }

    guard let inputImage = self.ciImage else {
        ImageError.ciImageError(self.ciImage).handle()
        return self
    }
    wpaFilter.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    wpaFilter.setValue(whiteColor, forKey: kCIInputColorKey)

    guard let output = wpaFilter.outputImage else {
        ImageError.filterError(wpaFilter).handle()
        return nil
    }
    guard let cgImage = context.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent) else {
        ImageError.cgImageError(output, output.extent).handle()
        return nil
    }


    return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
}
}
```

Your help would be highly appreciated. I checked if, the UIImage is there and it is.

The filter also doesn't work, but I didn't have time to check it out. However if anyone has a quick solution for that, it would be appreciated as well

**Update:**

I replaced

```
guard let inputImage = self.ciImage
```

with:

```
guard let inputImage = CIImage(image: self)
```

and it seams to work. But I don't really understand the difference. Could anyone please give an explanation?

Comment: According to the doc: of `var ciImage: CIImage? { get }`: `If the UIImage object was initialized using a CGImage, the value of the property is nil.`. Could explains the issue...

Comment: It was an image from the Asset catalog

Comment: All the time? Because for instance, if you do in pseudo code: `let image = UIImage.(name:"name"); image = image.applyWhitePointAdjustment(.redColor); image = image.applyWhitePointAdjustment(.blueColor);`, the second time it has been created through `return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)`, and then explain it.